# OpenMP not detected by clangd despite compile_commands.json

Tags: neovim, autocompletion

My program compiles fine, but within Vim (with CoC + clangd) I get the linting error: `#include <omp.h> 'omp.h' file not found (clang pp_file_not_found)`

I use `bear -- make` as described in https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html#project-setup, and it usually works for libraries I'm using.
With OpenMP, it creates this file:

```
[
  {
    "arguments": [
      "/usr/bin/g++",
      "-fopenmp",
      "-Wall",
      "-g",
      "-I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include/",
      "-c",
      "proj03.cpp"
    ],
    "directory": "/home/me/school/cs475/3",
    "file": "/home/me/school/cs475/3/proj03.cpp"
  }
]
```

Why does the error happen? What do I need to do to get clang to recognize OpenMP?

Comment: Welcome to vi SE. You can always [edit] your post to add information. Doing so is better than adding a comment to your own post.

Comment: Isn't that rather a question for your bear command what that is? I don't think this is vims responsibility here

Comment: Sounds more like CoC/clangd troubleshooting to me